# Apache mod_rewrite as proxy not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, mod-proxy

I'm trying to use apache as a proxy server to redirect some requests to a service running on a different port. I'm attempting to follow the instructions here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html

I've done exactly this to install (and nothing else):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

Then edited /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:9200/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9200/
```

Then finally, restarted apache2 (`sudo service apache2 restart`). Eventually, I'll add some real conditions to that rule, but I'm just trying to test it for now.

But it's not working. `curl -XGET localhost:80/foo` fails with a 404 response, `curl -XGET loaclhost:9200/foo` succeeds. Nothing useful in the error log or access log.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting your Apache reverse proxy commands to be something like this; note the `ProxyPass` setting as well as `ProxyRequests` and `ProxyPreserveHost` settings:

```
 <IfModule mod_proxy.c>

  # Proxy specific settings
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    AddDefaultCharset off
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9200/ 
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9200/ 

</IfModule>
```

I would also recommend you check the headers of the response output in `curl` by using the `-I` option like this:

```
curl -I localhost:80/foo
```

It should show you the exact response from the server so you can fully understand what might be failing and what might be working.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I should add that the reason I'm trying to do it using the RewriteRule is because I might eventually be wanting some fairly complex RewriteConds, moreso than what seems possible with just ProxyPass.

Comment: Is there a way to use those settings but only forward specific request methods? Taking a step back - what I'm looking to do is proxy only GET requests, and only those to specific paths, and reject all others.

I tried using settings like this, plus an additional rewrite rule, but it seemed like the proxy was happening before the rewrite. As an example, I added: `RewriteRule .* - [F]` but all requests still went through successfully.